# moving a child div to right using the arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery

the code :

Html :

```
<div id="Container" class="Container">
<div id="PLayer"  class="player" ></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .Container
 {
  width:200px;
   height:200px;
  }
 .player
{
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 background-color:Red;
 position: absolute;
 }   
</style>
```

js:

```
$("body").keydown(function (e) {

        var KeyID = e.KeyCode || e.which;
        if (KeyID === 39) //right 
        {
            $("#Player").animate({ 'right': '20px' });
        }
    });
```

but Player don't seem to move at all any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work but use class selector.

```
$(".Player").animate({ 'right': '+=20px' });
```

If you have multiple divs which have Player as class value then all div will move.

Comment: It won't work with an uppercase "P" - the class has a lowercase "p".

Comment: thank u for this perfect answer but how can i do a test to check whether the player has surpass the parent div border ?

Comment: You can do this by checking condition before executing this line.
You can get position of your parrent div like this.
var a = $(yourparrentDiv).position() so after this you can access position like 
a.top or a.left

Answer (score 1):

You should make it move right more 20px from it's current position:

```
$(".Player").animate({ 'right': '+=20px' });
```

Comment: yes you are right :) but now i want to check if the player surpasses the border of it's parent div how can i do it ?

Comment: You can read the parent div position, its size also and then base on them, you calculate the limitation of top and left of the player. I'm too lazy to make a demo here :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the case on the id. You have:

```
id="PLayer"
```

and:

```
$("#Player")
```

Change the uppercase "L" in the element's id to lowercase and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/V27DZ/1/

...assuming that you have the JavaScript code in a script block that appears after the element, or you have wrapped it in a document ready handler.

Note also that by animating the `right` property you are setting how far it is from the right-hand edge of the page. If you intend for it to simply move over 20px to the right of its current position, do this instead:

```
$("#Player").animate({ 'left': '+=20px' });
```

That is, add 20px to the current left position. Wouldn't hurt to give it an initial position too: http://jsfiddle.net/V27DZ/2/

Finally, note that you don't have to test `e.keyCode` because jQuery normalises `e.which` for you, but if you *do* test `e.keyCode` remember that JS is case sensitve and you need a lowercase "k".

Comment: oh shit hehe yeah you are right i fixed it and work perfectly